# Trendlines in google charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am using google charts library but could not draw a trendline may be because i am using a `string` as hAxis and `number` as vAxis, what i found till now is that it's impossible to draw a trendline until both axis are number, but i have seen example where Date as hAxis is used but i assume that's because that is comparable.
So can i draw a trendLine with xAxis as String?

My Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {'packages': ['corechart'], 'callback': drawChart});

    function drawChart() {
     var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      <g:each status="counter" var="row" in="${transactionsColumns}">
        data.addColumn("${row[0]}","${row[1]}");
        </g:each>
        var tempData=new Array();
        <g:each status="counter" var="row" in="${transactionsData}">
        var lowerArray=new Array();
        <g:each status="eIndex" var="element" in="${row}">

        <g:if test="${eIndex==0}">
        var column="${row[eIndex]}"
        lowerArray[${eIndex}]=column;
        </g:if>
        <g:else>
        var column=${row[eIndex]}
        lowerArray[${eIndex}]=column;
        </g:else>

        </g:each>
        tempData[${counter}]=lowerArray;
        </g:each>
     data.addRows(tempData);


     var options = {'title':"${transactionsColumns[1][1]}",
             'width':'auto',
             'height':'auto',

             trendlines: {
               0: {
                 visibleInLegend: true,
                 color: 'purple',
                 lineWidth: 10,
                 opacity: 0.2,
               }
             }
             };

     var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("lineChart${divId}"));
     chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
```

**EDIT:** After jmac help i was able to do this:
[image: Graph with string x-axis but actual a number]

now i got what i wanted on hovering at graph points, but not on x-axis itself it still showing number

**My code:** this is one cell

```
lowerArray[${eIndex}]= {v:${counter+1},f:column};  //LHS dont care about it. v:loop_var(1,2,3..),f:"MyString"
```

Comment: You can't draw a trendline with a string axis.  The domain axis (typically x-axis) and data axes (typically y-axis) must all be of a continuous data type ("number", "date", "datetime", or "timeofday") in order to generate a trendline.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a kludge to get around this.

Google supports having separate values for calculation and for display. You can give arbitrary numerical values to your data, and have it display as a string, allowing you to create a trendline.

For instance, if you have the following data set:

```
data.addColumn('string','Stations');
data.addColumn('number','Bentos Sold');
data.addRows([
  ['Tokyo',1],
  ['Shinagawa',2],
  ['Yokohama',3],
  ['Nagoya',4],
  ['Osaka',5]
]);
```

You can change this using `{v: , f:}` formatting as follows:

```
data.addColumn('number','Stations');
data.addColumn('number','Bentos Sold');
data.addRows([
  [{v:1, 'Tokyo'},1],
  [{v:2, 'Shinagawa'},2],
  [{v:3, 'Yokohama'},3],
  [{v:4, 'Nagoya'},4],
  [{v:5, 'Osaka'},5]
]);
```

Your axis values would still be 'Tokyo', 'Shinagawa', etc. but they would be calculated as numbers 1, 2, etc.

Comment: hey when i hover on points in my graphs it shows right x-axis value, so thanks, but on actual x-axis it showing random numbers, where i can read more about f: v: calc: options'??

Comment: @Sachin It isn't about the calculation options, you just have to set the proper number of gridlines. You can do this automagically with a javacscript function (counting the number of rows, for instance), or you can do it manually (making sure the number of gridlines matches the amount of data. Be sure you start at `min-1` for your axis min value, `max+1` for your max value, and then have a number of gridlines equal to the number of category labels.

Comment: As I explained, you need to set `hAxis` options for `min` and `max` and `gridlines` to match the number of categories you have on the X axis. Your edit does not tell me any of that...

Comment: hey thanks man for your help i appreciate it, but i got nothing to do with grid_line what my problem is in above picture x-axis are still number because of(v:1,f:'string'), i don't want 1 to be there i want 'string' to be there on x-axis and i did what you said about grid lines  hAxis:{minValue:0, maxValue: global+1,gridlines:{count : global}},  
I am only obsessed with getting string on x-axis please help me

Comment: Sorry, it looks like this may not properly display the axis values. There were several workarounds that I posted somewhere, but I can't find the right one right now. Take a look through [my answers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1933347/jmac?tab=answers) maybe searching for axis or labels.

Answer (score 1):

```
function drawMultipleTrendlineChart() {
    var chartType='columnChart';
    var collection = [];
    var chart = {
    "collection":[{
   "0": ["date", "Data"],
   "1": ["number", "Valor 1"],
   "2": ["number", "Valor 2"],
   "3": ["number", "Valor 3"],  
   "4": ["number", "Valor 4"],       
},
   {
   "0": ['2013-3-2', 200, 1000],
   "1": ['2013-4-2', 500, 650],
   "2": ['2013-5-2', 700, 550],
   "3": ['2013-6-2', 300, 95],
   "4": ['2013-8-2', 200, 75],
   "5": ['2013-9-2', 900, 1275],  
   "6": ['2013-10-2', 900, 1275],  
}]
};


    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            var valores = [];
            for(var h=0; h <= chart.collection[0][0].length; h++){
                data.addColumn(chart.collection[0][h][0],
                chart.collection[0][h][1]);
            }
            var total = chart.collection[1][0].length;
            var params = [];

            for(var i=0; i<= total; i++){

                    var dataString = chart.collection[1][i][0];
                    var dataVenda = dataString.split('-');
                    var ano = eval(dataVenda[0]);
                    var mes = eval(dataVenda[1]);
                    var dia = eval(dataVenda[2]);
                    valores[i] = [new Date(ano, mes, dia),
                                  chart.collection[1][i][1],
                                  chart.collection[1][i][2]];

params[i] = '"'+i+'":{"showR2": false, "labelInLegend": \'valores\', "type": "exponencial", "visibleInLegend": true}';

            }
var parseData = eval('var dataParse = {'+params.join(',')+'}');
            data.addRows(valores);
          var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
                fractionDigits: 2,
                prefix: 'R$:'
            });
            formatter.format(data, 1);
            var dateFormatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
                pattern: 'MMM yyyy'
            });
            dateFormatter.format(data, 0);
            var chartHeight = 400;
            var chartWidth = 600;
            var chartOptions = {
                tooltip: {
                    isHtml: true
                },
                title: chart.title,
                isStacked: true,
                width: chartWidth,
                height: chartHeight,
                //colors: ['#0000D8', '#00dddd'],
                hAxis: {
                    title: 'Vendas por distribuidor',
                    slantedText: false,
                    slantedTextAngle: 45,
                    textStyle: {
                        fontSize: 10
                    },
                    format: 'dd-MM-yyyy'
                },
                chartArea: {
                    left: 50,
                    top: 20,
                    width: (chartWidth - 10),
                    height: (chartHeight - 90)
                }
            };
            chartOptions.trendlines = dataParse;
            chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('multipleTrendChart'));
            chart.draw(data, chartOptions);
        }

google.load('visualization', '1', {
    packages: ['corechart'],
    callback: drawMultipleTrendlineChart
});
```